# fixed height Slider for any device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve a full screen option for any device. There is a slider along with 04 boxes which & I am trying to show all of them in full screen on any device. I have almost achieved it by using `.carousel-inner {min-height:83vh;} .carousel-inner img{max-height:83vh;}` but its stretching the image. I need a better solution.

```css
.container-fluid {
  margin:0;
  Padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://logohour.com/images/bg2.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://logohour.com/images/bg3.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-xs-3">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x75/111111" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x75/333333" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x75/666666" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x75/999999" alt="...">
</div>
</div>
<br><br>




<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: what you described sounds more like dynamic height since you want the height to change depending on the viewport size.

Comment: Yes even as I have mentioned that I have almost achieved it by adjusting carousel min height and its image max height but of course i understand it will fixed the height and image may get stretch.

Comment: fixed and dynamic are antonyms.  I'm just suggesting that the title of your question might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in css only Write This

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  height:500px;
}
```

If I use the provided class so its also effecting width but when I used min-height with your class so its working fine but only on laptop and small screen sizes but also stretching. its not working with large screens

Answer (score 0):

Plz use it

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
       function mySlider() {
       var winH = $(window).height();
       var winW = $(window).width();
       var fourBoxH = $('#fourBox').height();
       var finalSliderH = winH - fourBoxH;
        $('.carousel-inner').css( {'height' : finalSliderH+'px', 'width' : winW+'px',  });
   };
   window.onload = mySlider();
});
</script>
```

css >>

```
.carousel-inner { }
.carousel-inner img { width:100% }
```

on 4 box container add id >>

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="fourBox">
```